# How to filter in Graphql GitHub API by MergeableState

Tags: javascript, json, github, graphql, github-actions

The following code block returns a list of pull requests with their mergeability status such as 'MERGEABLE', 'CONFLICTING', etc.

Is there any way to filter inline by [mergeablestate](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/enums#mergeablestate)?

I can filter the result obtained after this using js or anything else. I wanted to understand how to do it in a Graphql script. Looked up the docs could not find a way.

```
{
      repository(owner: "rikesh_kamra", name: "git-sticker") {
        pullRequests(first: 1, states: [OPEN]) {
          nodes {
            id
            number
            changedFiles
            deletions
            mergeable
            author {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried

```
pullRequests(first: 1, states: [OPEN], mergeable: [MERGEABLE))
```

But got an error saying mergeable is not a valid argument for pullRequests.